# Live Agent- Translation

Tags: liveagent, pre-chat

I have developed a pre-chat form with French as its language. I could translate everything except for the attached image. Can someone please help me understand what I need to do to translate this message into French?
I reckon, 'Please fill out this field' is automatically shown up when we add required=true on the input in VF page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Fill out" is somewhat idiomatic, but the closest translation would be

> S'il vous plait, remplissez cette cellule